# flot exception invalid dimention for flot height = 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

This is my chart flot options

```
var chartOptions = {
               xaxis: {
                   min: 0,
                   max: result.length + 1,
                   ticks: ticks
               },
               grid: {
                   hoverable: true,
                   clickable: false,
                   borderWidth: 0
               },
               bars: {
                   show: true,
                   barWidth: 1,
                   //barWidth:null,
                   fill: true,
                   lineWidth: 1,
                   order: true,
                   lineWidth: 0,
                   fillColor: { colors: [{ opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 1 }] }
               },

               tooltip: true,
               tooltipOpts: {
                   content: '%s: %y'
               },
               colors: App.chartColors
           };
           var holder = $('#vertical-chart');

           if (holder.length) {
               $.plot(holder, data, chartOptions);
           }
```

I got exception:

`invalid dimention for flot hieght =0`

1. There is no problem with html because I can draw another chart using the same html

help please

#### Update

This is the HTML

```
<div style="width: 45%; height:300px; float: left; margin-left:5%">                      
    <div id="vertical-chart" class="chart-holder" style="border:1px solid #D5D5D5; margin-top:2px">
        <canvas class="overlay" width="479" height="265"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By "no problem with the html," do you mean you can plot within `vertical-chart` using other data or other options?  What are `vertical-chart`'s styles?

Comment: @RickHitchcock yes I can plot using other options and I will update the question for u

Comment: I haven't used flot with a canvas, but I know its container needs dimensions.  Does adding height and width to `vertical-chart` make a difference?

Comment: @RickHitchcock as you see, I already added a hight and width for the `vertical-chart`, but still have the problem

Comment: @RickHitchcock do you want to print the `data` variable for you, maybe you can test or somethign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may fix your problem:  Change the canvas class from `overlay` to `flot-overlay`.

The class name was changed due to a request here:

**https://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=540**

You'll see the API change described in the second paragraph here:

**https://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/NEWS.txt**

Without this change, the canvas is being deleted during the `plot` call, leaving `vertical-chart` without a height.

If this doesn't fix your problem, it would be useful to see your `data` object.

Comment: changing the class didn't help, this is the data variable `[{"label":"asdf","data":[[1,1],[2,7]]},{"label":"aaa","data":[[1,1],[2,2]]},{"label":"asdfasdf","data":[[1,0],[2,5]]}]`, plus there is something weird, when I changed the whole script to a static data (ie working example) I kept having the same error

Comment: I have successfully created a flot chart using that data and by changing the class to `flot-overlay`:  http://jsfiddle.net/obwsv9g5/  I commented out `max`, `ticks`, and `colors` since I don't know those values.

Comment: Perhaps you're using an older version of flot?

Comment: I am out of my mind, why it is working with you and it is working with all the other pages except this page. can you access my pc please?

Comment: It just worked, can you believe that I forgot to add ` <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/App.css" />` OMG I can't believe that, thanks man +1

Comment: Good deal!  Glad you got it going.